# How to implement the module pattern with public statics?

Tags: javascript

My public statics are the interfaces to user actions - i.e. the GUI.  Here are two that bind to when the user hits enter on the SignIn and SignUp form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the question but why not in this way?

```
/**
 *Control
 */

var Control = ( function () 
{
    var Control = function ( ) // constructor 
    {
    };
    Control.prototype.function_1 = function( ) // public - instance 
    {
    };
    Control.in = function()
    {
        new Control( 'signin' ).invoke();
    };
    Control.up = function()
    {
        new Control( 'signup' ).invoke();
    };
    Control.out = function()
    {
        AjaxNew.repeatUse( '&ajax_type=ControlSignOut', function( server_response_text ) { ajaxType( server_response_text, 0, 'simple' ); } );
    };
    Control.try = function()
    {
        AjaxNew.repeatUse( '&ajax_type=ControlTryIt', function( server_response_text ) { ajaxType( server_response_text, 0, 'simple' ); } );
    };
    return Control;
} () );
```

Comment: Control.in would be accessible in the global scope..i.e. the most outer?

Comment: Yes of course. It depends on where Control is declared. (Sorry to be late)